# Efficient way to search large data set based on several fields

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, search

I want to know that what will be the best way to search the large data set based on different fields. 
For example, Person object is defined as following:

```
Person:
    first name
    last name
    phone numbers
```

I have 100k objects of Person type and I want to search for a particular person based on any of the field ?

I tried to sort the data set using different fields so that I can perform the search operation in O(logn) time, but I know that's not the correct way.

Comment: You can try [`Boost.MultiIndex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html): "*The Boost Multi-index Containers Library provides a class template named multi_index_container which enables the construction of containers maintaining one or more indices with different sorting and access semantics*"

Comment: Thanks for the response.I can easily use this library but I want to develop my own solution.

Comment: What kind of flow do you use to build your structure? Would `insert_all->build_once->search` scenario fit your needs? I.e. do you need frequent insert/delete?

Comment: The insertion will be in bulk and then there will be large number of searches based on any field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one answer to this, because the right answer depends (heavily) upon how much you care about speed vs. extra storage.

If you want absolute maximum speed, and don't care at all about using extra storage, yes, you can create three copies of the data, one sorted by each field, and when a search is entered, just use the appropriate one. This may not be nearly as awful an option is it might first appear. Let's assume your strings average about 10 bytes apiece, so the overall size of the struct is ~30 bytes. 100'000 of those gives roughly 3 megabytes per copy, for a grand total of about 9 megabytes. At one time that would have been clearly prohibitive -- but with a typical machine now having at least 8 *gigabytes* of RAM, it's not nearly so terrible.

Assuming you rule that out, the next most obvious possibility would be to build indexes into the raw data -- put the raw data into one array, then build one index for each field, where each entry in the index contains the data for one field, and a pointer/subscript to the main data. Each index entry can be ~14 bytes, so each index is about half the size of the overall data. With only three fields you don't save a lot, but you do save some -- and at an *extremely* minimal cost in complexity. With more fields, you'd save even more.

Another possibility would be to implement your indices as hash tables. The primary advantage here is that you can avoid storing date repeatedly. For example, if you compute a 16-bit hash with 2 entries per bucket, you can store one index in ~512K bytes. If a bucket is full, but neither entry matches your input, you re-hash and try another bucket. Keep going until you either find your item or find an empty bucket.

Comment: +1 for exploring the alternatives. Why would the index entries in the second case be ~14 bytes? All you need for each index entry is a pointer to the data (4 or 8 bytes, depending on 32 or 64 bit), and you have a separate comparison function for each of the indexes. It's just calling `binary_search` with the proper comparison function.

Comment: @JimMischel: In the second case, what I was thinking of, at least, was an index that contained a copy of the "key" data, along with the index/pointer to the corresponding record. It's certainly possible to just have an array of pointers/indices in the correct order too--yet another trade-off between speed and memory usage (more indirection generally reduces speed).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Since, i have already done the first part, I will definitely try your second and third approach

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`Boost.MultiIndex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html):

> The Boost Multi-index Containers Library provides a class template named multi_index_container which enables the construction of containers maintaining one or more indicies with different sorting and access semantics:

---

But if you want to try yourself - then one the simplest solutions will be: use one container for all data, and in addition maintain several maps with appropriate indices's:

```
class Indixer
{
    vector<Record> values; // without specific order
    unordered_map<field_type1, Record*> index1; // Search: O(1) average
    unordered_map<field_type2, Record*> index2; // Search: O(1) average
    map<field_type3, Record*> index3; // Search: O(log N) worst case
public:
    // ...
};
```

You can use `std::unordered_map` in order to get O(1) average access. Here is example:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Record
{
    string first_name, last_name;
};

class Indexer
{
    typedef vector<Record> Container;
    typedef Record *Handle;
    Container values;
    unordered_map<string, Handle> first_name_index, last_name_index;

public:
    Indexer(Container &&x) : values(move(x))
    {
        for(auto &x : values)
        {
            first_name_index[x.first_name] = &x;
            last_name_index[x.last_name] = &x;
        }
    }
    const Record &first_name(const string &x)
    {
        return *first_name_index[x];
    }
    const Record &last_name(const string &x)
    {
        return *last_name_index[x];
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Record> v = {{"F1", "L1"}, {"F2", "L2"}};
    Indexer x(move(v));

    cout << x.first_name("F1").last_name << endl;
    cout << x.first_name("F2").last_name << endl;

    cout << x.last_name("L1").first_name << endl;
    cout << x.last_name("L2").first_name << endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
L1
L2
F1
F2
```

[**Live Demo on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c69d72141a63f482)